# how to get all tasks in background from start /b in windows

Tags: laravel, jobs

I am trying to run [queue](/questions/tagged/queue) in [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) through start /b in windows

But I  want to know how many tasks are running in the background
I am trying to run crone and job in laravel through

```
start /b php artisan ...... command
```

in windows

or how to run crone job in laravel on windows 10 or 11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlmhe.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.